# Is there any way convert list of strings in to Custom setting

Tags: customsetting

is there any way to convert list of string to custom settings.
i know we can convert list of strings to sobject.
please advice me

```
String objName = 'Account';
String query = 'Select Id From '+objName+ ' Limit 10';
List<SObject> objL = Database.query(query);
system.debug('datea====='+objL);
```

like above snippet is it possible to convert strings to custom setting as sobjecttype

Comment: Where is your list of string? What do you want the end result to be? For reference, I would like to know, how can you make a list of string into SObject? Please edit your question to the point.

Comment: Why? what are you trying to accomplish by converting a set to a custom setting? What advantage would doing that offer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to understand what you want to ask.
My guess is you want to execute below code for custom setting as well-

```
String objName = 'Account';
String query = 'Select Id From '+objName+ ' Limit 10';
List objL = Database.query(query);
system.debug('datea====='+objL);
```

If yes, yeah you can pass the custom setting API Name in objName variable.

```
String objName = 'CustomSettingAPIName__c';
String query = 'Select Id From '+objName+ ' Limit 10';
List objL = Database.query(query);
system.debug('datea====='+objL);
```